# Can I revert File Names back to a previous file name?

Tags: list, datasheet, rename

I changed file names by mistake while in Datasheet View by dragging the corner of the top row down. The file names that changed need to be changed back to their previous and correct name.

Comment: did you open a document library in datasheet view or List?

Comment: Datasheet view. It seems like once you change a filename, there is no way of knowing what the original filename was called.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you have versioning turn on for the library can you roll back.  BTW, you probably only changed the Name OR the Title OR the filename field.  One of the others, if added to your datasheet view might give you enough information to correct your issue.

Comment: Versioning is turned on. I "restored" a previous version and that didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, you may have changed it more times than you have versioning iterances.  See if there are other columns you can add to your view that maintained the data you overwrote.  If there is, you can copy and paste from there.

Answer (score 0):

If it is Document library and you open it with Datasheet view.
then you can simply edit the Name cell of the concern file and change the file name what it was before.

Comment: How do you know what the file name was before the change? Every version's File Name changed to the current file's name so there's no way of knowing what it was named (presumably).